# Commons Confuguration - how to specify string " , "

Tags: java, configuration

I use [Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html) to store several strings.

I need to specify the string `,` (blank comma blank).

According to the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html), I need to do specify in the properties file the following string: `\u0020\,\u0020`

When I try to read it from the configuration file, I receive just `,` (comma).

**EDIT:**

The conf file is:

```
my.conf.separator=\u0020\,\u0020
```

The code is something like:

```
Parameters params = new Parameters();
File propertiesFile = new File("config.properties");

FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder =
    new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
    .configure(params.fileBased()
        .setFile(propertiesFile));
try
{
    Configuration config = builder.getConfiguration();
    String separator = config.getString("my.conf.separator");
}
catch(ConfigurationException cex)
{
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. Option 1: URLEncode the String Option 2: Base64 Encode it

Comment: Yeah I thought of adding manual processing of the string, but I'd like to check whether there is a non-workaround way.